# Offline sync with Dropbox API v2

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

With the Dropbox Sync API there was a method `[DBFile writeContentsOfFile]` which would sync the file at a later time if the internet connection was offline.

Is there a similar function in the new Dropbox API v2?

I've found a method on `DBFilesRoutes -uploadData:inputData:`, which works fine for normal upload, but fails with an error if there's no internet connection...and unfortunately it doesn't sync later when the connection is restored.

Perhaps using `DBFilesRoutes -uploadSessionStartData:` is the solution (which I'll attempt shortly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately the official Dropbox API v2 SDKs don't offer offline support like that. We'll consider it a feature request.

The difference between `uploadData` and `uploadSessionStartData` is that `uploadData` is for uploading files in one call, whereas `uploadSessionStartData` is used along with `uploadSessionAppendV2Data` and `uploadSessionFinishData` to upload larger files in multiple pieces.